# Get images height, before they are loaded

Tags: php, html, css

So here is my problem, I know the width of the images, but I don't know the height, and I'm using a preloader, my problem is that when the images are loading...the content under the images bounces down...when it's fully loaded, If I had fixed images width&height it will be easy to solve this, just set them using width and height attributes and it will look ok.

But is there a way to set the height before the page is rendered, maybe using PHP or so.

Comment: If you're pulling image addresses out of a database and you don't know what images will be loaded (so you don't know height), it would probably be faster and more efficient to store the image dimensions in the database.  Otherwise you're going to ask the server to do a lot of extra work on each pageload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can get the hight and width via imagesx and imagesy then print it.

```
<?php
$img = 'image.jpg';
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
$width  = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);
print '<img src="'.$img.'" height="'.$height.'" width="'.$width.'" alt="" />';
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) on the server side with php to get image height and add that data properly to html. If you have too many images and you don't want to go though them every time the page loads, then consider caching this data in database somewhere